# Listview with multiple strings

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a Listview with multiple strings.

Right now I have a function that it will do

```
       while(i <= 10){
           //GETS DATA FROM WEBPAGE ETC
           a = DATAFROMWEBPAGE1;
           b = DATAFROMWEBPAGE2;
           c = DATAFROMWEBPAGE3
       }
```

10 times with 10 different sections from the webpage and I wanted to put this in a list view with 3 textviews showing a, b, c. But I'm having a very hard time doing so.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to display three strings in each row of the ListView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a custom ListAdapter to do this:

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter (this);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    adapter.addAdapterItem(new AdapterItem("first", "second", "third");
}
view.setListAdapter(adapter);
```

class AdapterItem:

```
public class AdapterItem {
  public String first;
  pubilc String second;
  public String third;

  public AdapterItem(String first, String second, String third) {
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
    this.third = third;
  }
}
```

class MyAdapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<AdapterItem> items;

public void addAdapterItem(AdapterItem item) {
  items.add(item); 
}

public int getCount() {
  return items.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
  return items.get(position);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
  View rowView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rowLayout);
  TextView firstTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.firstView);
  firstTextView.setText(items.get(postion).first);
  // do the same with second and third
  return rowView;
}
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout android:Layout_width=".." android:layout_height="..">
  <TextView android:id="firstView" />
  <TextView android:id="secondView" />
  <TextView android:id="thirdView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The code is not complete, just to give you the idea:

-You create a new ListAdapter that handles your items

- You can store your items in an extra class (`AdapaterItem` in this example) inside your adapter
- Your `ListAdapter` implementation has to provide common methods like `getCount()` and `getItem()`
- Within the `getView(..)` method you can return your custom view for each row. If you want to display 3 different text messages you have to define 3 Textviews in your layout and assign the strings in `getView(..)`

Comment: I get "E/AndroidRuntime( 6240): java.lang.NullPointerException" on this line:     AdapterItem test = new AdapterItem(a, b, c);
    
    adapter.addAdapterItem(test);  why would I get a null pointer?

Comment: Maybe your adapter is null? You need to create your adapter object before you can assign items to it (MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter (...)).

Comment: I have "MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter ();" before I start adding stuff

Answer (score 1):

First, create a layout that organizes the views you want to appear in a single row. (See [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html) for an example that groups two strings and an image.) Let's say you save this in a layout file called `row_layout.xml` and it has three TextViews with ids `t1`, `t2`, and `t3`.

Second, decide what data structure you are going to use for your data. We'll suppose it's an array of arrays of String, where each element contains the three strings you want to display in each row.

Third, you need to create a custom list adapter. If you're using the above array data structure, it might look something like this (adapted from [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)):

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String[]> {
private final Context context;
private final String[][] values;

public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[][] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.row_layout, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.t1);
    TextView textView2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.t2);
    TextView textView3 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.t3);
    textView1.setText(values[position][0]);
    textView2.setText(values[position][3]);
    textView3.setText(values[position][2]);

    return rowView;
}
}
```

Finally, in your ListActivity, add this in onCreate:

```
setListAdapter(new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, values));
```

where `values` is the array of string arrays that you want displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [official ListView tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)?

- Create an XML file as your layout that will contain the 3 TextViews. This will be your list item
- Create Custom Adapter class by extending `BaseAdapter`. In this class you will pass the 3 values for each textbox and fill them accordingly.
- Set the `setListAdapter` to your new collection, passing the layout as parameter and your custom adapter.

It takes a bit of work, but in the end, you will learn a lot.