# uniform Alignment in second string added in listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I am populating a listview row with 2 strings in it. 1st is the number and then name. I want my second string to be in the same position as the first added in the listview like in this picture below.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632529/listview-with-multiple-strings

Comment: Have a look at this post. You only have to populate the textviews of each row (in your case 2 textviews per row) in the order you need

Comment: I don't want it to be in textview. What I want is it to be in Listview. Is there a way in doing that? thanks

Comment: yes, but by default a listview row has a textview to show data, so you should override and create a custom adapter with two textviews per row, one to show the number an another one to show the string. have a look at offical documentation: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"   
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView 
     android:text="1" 
     android:id="@+id/number"   
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>

   <TextView 
    android:text="David" 
     android:id="@+id/textstring"   
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following xml layout as custom layout for `ListView` individual list items :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:text="David"
        android:id="@+id/textstring"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

About your comment to your post. You cant possible put a text on your list item without a textView. Perhaps you can put a fix width of the first TextView so that the second TextView will begin in uniform, just make sure the width is enough for the text(in this case a number) in the first TextView to be displayed.

```
<LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal">
      <TextView
           android:layout_width="48dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/string1"/>
      <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/string2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't want it to be in textview. What I want is it to be in Listview. Is there a way in doing that? thanks

Comment: You cant put a text on a listview. You need a layout of your list item first, like what I wrote above and use it in your adapter's getView().

Comment: You need to make you custom adapter that extends BaseAdapter and use the layout in the getView method of the class.